# Applying style to material 3 widget TextInputLayout leads to crash

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

XML lines in which I am using TextInputLayout which have dropdown menus to select as an input.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/address_input_state"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/address_input_town_city"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text_fill_address">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="none"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And I have used material theming as my parent theme.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.EcomApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->

    </style>
```

Now I am unable to understand why using style in textInputLayout leads to crash all the time with error message error inflating class . Image of error is attached. [image]

Comment: I have found the mistake and answered it myself below.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing a mistake in applying style to TextInput. My theme should be from MaterialComponents in place of Material3. My parent theme inherits from MaterialComponent and so should TextInput be.

Correct code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/address_input_state"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/address_input_town_city"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text_fill_address">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="none"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```